# Why this $f_r(x)$ is $\mu$-measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm reading Measure theory and fine properties of functions by Evans, 1st edition. In the page 39, Proof of Claim #3 defines a function $f_r(x)$

$$f_r(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{\nu(B(x,r))}{\mu(B(x,r))} \quad\text{ if } \mu(B(x,r))>0\\
\\
+\infty \quad \text{ if } \mu(B(x,r))=0
\end{cases}$$
where $\mu$ and $\nu$ are two Radon measures, $r$ is a positive constant and $B(x,r)$ denotes a **closed ball** centered at $x$ with radius $r$. Then the text states that

> the functions $x\mapsto \mu(B(x,r))$ and $x\mapsto \nu(B(x,r))$ are upper semicontinuous and thus Borel measurable. **Consequently, for every $r>0$, $f_r(x)$ is $\mu$-measurable.**

I understand the first sentence. But I can't figure out why the text could claim easily that $f_r(x)$ is $\mu$-measurable ? Any hint ?

Comment: This is a definition chase.  $\mu$ is a Radon measure, in particular a Borel measure, so Borel measurable is the same thing as $\mu$-measurable.

Comment: So you mean, the numerator and the denumerator are Borel measurable, thus $f_r(x)$ is Borel measurable. So $f_r(x)$ is $\mu$-measurable (and $\nu$-measurable) since $\mu$ (and $\nu$) is a Borel measure. Right ?

Comment: @D_S But how to handle the case where $\mu(B(x,r))=0$ ?

Comment: @D_S I guess the argument is like this. We know $x\mapsto\mu(B(x,r))$ is Borel measurable. Then $\{x|\mu(B(x,r))=0\}$ is a Borel set. Hence $f_r^{-1}(+\infty)$ is a Borel set. Combined with the argument above for the case $\mu(B(x,r))>0$, $f_r(x)$ is Borel measurable. Do you think this is OK ?

Comment: Yes, it's okay.